# Could not translate host name "localhost" to address: Unknown server error

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt, database-connection

I'm developing a Windows Service with Qt-Framework and i can't connect to my Database (Postgresql).

But I have a Client Application in which i use the exact same Database connection and it works.

```
//driver
mDB = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");

//connection
void Monitoring::DbConnection(QSqlDatabase mDB)
{
    mDB.setHostName("localhost");
    mDB.setDatabaseName("testdb");
    mDB.setPort(5432);
    mDB.setPassword("test");
    mDB.setUserName("12345");
    if (!mDB.open()) {
            qDebug() << "Database Error ! " << mDB.lastError();
            mMessagebox.critical(0, "Error", "An Error occurred! " 
                        + mDB.lastError().text());
            qApp->exit();
    }
}
```

The lastError says:

> could not translate host name "localhost" to address: Unknown server
>   error

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use the IP address in the `setHostName()` field, if it is the same machine use `127.0.0.1` which is the IP address trasnlation for `localhost`

Comment: I tried it it returns a different error now.
`mDB.setHostName("127.0.0.1");`
`could not create socket: Invalid argument (0x00002726/10022)`

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the argument you are making a copy for the object and maybe the `=` operator is not copyin all the data.

Try the code with the following with the `&` in the argument:

```cpp
//connection
void Monitoring::DbConnection(QSqlDatabase& mDB)
{
    mDB.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    mDB.setDatabaseName("testdb");
    mDB.setPort(5432);
    mDB.setPassword("test");
    mDB.setUserName("12345");
    if (!mDB.open()) {
            qDebug() << "Database Error ! " << mDB.lastError();
            mMessagebox.critical(0, "Error", "An Error occurred! " 
                        + mDB.lastError().text());
            qApp->exit();
    }
}
```